# How to optimize a slow MySQL Query (via PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to run the following mySQL query via a piece of PHP code on the front end of a website.  For some reason when I run this on my AWS instance the performance is abysmal.  However, when I run it localhost (wamp) I have no problems at all.  It will even return results for larger data sets. I am somewhat of a novice when it comes to mySQL.  Thoughts?

```
SELECT *
FROM bigfoot
WHERE family_id IN
(
   SELECT family_id AS family_id 
   FROM bigfoot 
   WHERE user_email = '$email' 
   GROUP BY family_id
)
```

As you can see, the primary element in gathering specific row data for this query is family_id.  However, only the first row of each family_id contains an email address of which in this case is used as the basis for the query.  I have searched various posts in the form, but am still unsure of how to move forward.

Thanks in advance,

Randy

Comment: are the table structures the same on both deployments? can you show us the table structures?

Comment: Learn to use [`EXPLAIN`](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/).

Comment: Yes, I replicated the current table on the AWS platform to my localhost machine for testing.  In terms of structure, there roughly a total of 40 columns and maybe 300,000 vertical lines of data in those columns.  Does this help?

Comment: not really. a 'describe' or 'show create' output helps best. or, better still, as per Jason McCreary, run 'explain' on your command. here's an overview:

http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/

Comment: a join is necessary off the top of my head, even if a join on self, not a slow correlated subquery. need `show create table bigfoot`  ... certainly would be fast with proper, and an index on email / family_id, not certain what the group by on that column is for !  But it is not our call to sprinkle indexes everywhere, as index strategy must dance the tango with all else that is going on. So, run the highlighted above, publish it, we will know more

Comment: Are your tables indexed at all?

Comment: No probably not, would I index only specific fields?  Sorry, I am really new at this, but having fun!

Comment: Yes, because the user email address is only printed on the first row of data inserted into each family_id.  For instance, a family_id of 5 may have ten rows associated with it, but the email address of the contributor is only printed on the first of ten.  I am using the email to then collect all of the associated family_id's.

Comment: `SELECT distinct family_id AS family_id FROM bigfoot WHERE user_email = '$email'` for the subquery might help. Not sure though.

Comment: thing is Monkey you want to ditch subqueries. thing is in my head at least :>

Comment: @DrewPierce I agree but I would go as far as saying that it is situational. This simple query could perform the same as a properly formatted join but only OP could tell us that after some testing.

Comment: true, then there is the whole CBO issue, which I can't speak to. And like you said, and I did, it is not our call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go out on a limb, why not.

I think this would be blazing fast:

```
select b1.*
from bigfoot b1
join bigfoot b2
on b2.family_id=b1.family_id
and b2.user_email='$email'
```

**assuming** you had a composite index on bigfoot (family_id,email)   ... a big assumption. plus an index on email

It does show however how to lose the correlated subquery.

b2 would be isolated to email, getting family. b1 will be all for that family, if I did it right

Comment: You are a rockstar!  This works excellent!  Thanks again, I think I am going to learn up on the EXPLAIN statements and JOIN.  Thanks all!

Comment: glad to be helpful, don't need the Correct Answer. Someone else might have better. Good luck